# Process builder does not fire when a workflow Task is created

Tags: workflow, process-builder, tasks

I have a workflow that creates a task , and also a process builder that does a field update when task is created/edited.

The process builder works when I do it manually, however it does not seem to fire when a task is created from a workflow.

Is that how it works?

Comment: What are the criteria for the process builder to execute (on after insert)? Workflow itself generally isn't recursive to avoid infinite loops. If process builders fired on what happens because of workflow, that would have the potential for that to occur. Triggers will execute after workflow fires in the same execution context, but I'm assuming you're likely referring to time based workflow that creates a task. Is that the case?

Comment: Process builder fires when a Task is created/edited , it has to do a field update (Populates [Task].AccountId to a lookup field on task.) In that way I can display Account Name on tasks created.

Comment: However if a task is created via a workflow (criteria not related to my process builder at all). That task created does not populate the lookup field. Hence these auto created tasks do not have a Account Name lookup field values.

Comment: @Cheryl I am facing the same issue. Were you able to find a resolution?